# Where is the open Java client for ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, java, esri-geometry-api-java

Short of hacking the Android SDK into your Java project, are there any Java clients that can consume and work with ArcGIS Server services? e.g. create Feature Sets, Geometries, perform Queries/Geoprocess tasks, etc.. 
Similar to what you can use the Javascript or ObjC SDK's. Though I don't need to visualize, only interact with the services. 
The closest thing I've seen is the Geometry API:
https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java
No, I don't want ArcObjects or any SDK that requires some $$license.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS for Server can provide a number of Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) web services (e.g. WMS, WFS, WFS-T, WMTS, WCS, WPS).

For a full list at ArcGIS 10.1 see this **[page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003700000002000000)**.

Consequently, any Java client that can consume and work with these OGC services, can consume and work with services provided by ArcGIS for Server.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ArcGIS Java web services API. It´s a SOAP SDK.
You can [download it for free](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/soap/10.1/index.html#/java/01vp00000044000000/) even without having to sign in with your Esri account.

For a REST approach you can use ArcGIS Server endpoints (REST API). You only need a good JSON parser (e.g. Jackson).